# For XGBoost Is there a way to find feature importances on per inference basis

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, xgboost

I'm using an XGBRegressor model and have been able to look holistically at which of my features are most predictive by just accessing:

```
clf.feature_importances_
```

However, I was reading online it should be possible to find which features are most important for a particular inference.

```
one_data_point = ...
clf.predict([one_data_point])[0].feature_importances_  # Doesn't work obviously
```

This seems like it would be some accumulation of the paths the decision tree took. Is there any way to do this?